# Ignore files in a folder but still add it to Git

Tags: git, frameworks, gitignore

I have included Zend in my project and this library has about 2.8k files. Since this is a PHP framework, the chances for my team to ever touch this folder is very low.

Question is, how should I gitignore this folder but still keep this framework in the repositories? Is this even possible? i.e., I want `Zend` to be cloned in every `clone`, but I don't want git to scan these folders on every `status` or `commit` - it takes 3 seconds or more depends on my PC status.

- submodule? But this is not a remote repo, or which means I need to create a remote repo for Zend
- gitignore, and `add -f` seems added the framework back but all files are tracked

The reason to ignore the folder is to speed up the commit speed. This is not the only framework we use and the other framework has more than thousands of files as well - on windows machine it's unbearably slow.

**EDIT**

It seems like it has been answered before and the only way is to use submodule:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810901/534862

And it seems like `update-index` is one of the way thou:

- http://justaddwater.dk/2009/12/07/how-to-make-git-ignore-files-that-already-exist-in-your-project/

Comment: I'm using a big framework in a project too and I don't have problems with speed. You need to untrack the files of Zend (remove them), commit the project and add in .gitignore the folder of the framework, so them it will be ignored and you will can commit again.

Comment: It's slow on my windows machine although it has been gc'ed. I know it has no issue on *nix but how could I ask git to ignore this framework? I tried to ignore and add -f. It seems that git still knows I secretly modified one of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a submodule. Make it a remote repo by hosting it on github. you will have a nice light weight repo now that only includes the work the team does. Even if you want to update Zend, you can do that but it won't affect the day-to-day once that's done.

Comment: submodule is one way, thanks, but I want to reserve it as my last resort - in case it's impossible to achieve such requirement. Thanks!

Comment: why is it a last resort? It's made for this type of problem.

Comment: As in I don't want to host existing frameworks as a public repo - it doesn't make sense and it doesn't belong to me

Comment: Is zend not open source? You can host it on bitbucket for free as a private repo then.

Comment: Of course I can re-host them (zend, twig, google-api, extjs..), the question is whether this is the only way to solve this problem. If it is then I will spend some time do the thing then.

Comment: most open source stuff is now on git - and most likely git hub (some others are bitbucket and codeplex). You could also house it within your organization. Things like gitolite make administrating multiple repos a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put a file in the Zend directory, like `.gitkeep`, and then add the following to your .gitignore:

```
# ignore everything in Zend
Zend/*
# except .gitkeep
!Zend/.gitkeep
```

This will have the effect of ignoring everything in that directory, but will keep the directory around for purposes of .gitkeep.

I am not 100% sure that git will do the smart thing and not scan the directory for other files, but I am pretty hopefull.

Comment: The problem is to ignore everything in the folder yet having all the files appears on every clones. The closest would be submodule, or even the update-index thingy.

Answer (score -1):

Use the git rm command with --cached option. With it, git will destroy all tracks of the framework. So, you insert the framework again in the project folder and add it to the .gitignore. I'm looking for a reference to you.

**Edit:**

I found. Take a look [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Removing-Files).

Comment: How is it going to work? I tried `git rm -r --cached <path to Zend>` and removed the whole Zend from tracking, and pushed to github. Github  has my `Zend` removed, but this is not the case as I wished to share `Zend` across teams. How should I add it back to github without tracking it? (Sounds funny lolx)