# adding certain files (images) to git without versioning

Tags: git

I am having a dilemma right now regarding storing images:

- right now my project has just started.
- During the first few development iterations, I am seeing that there will be lots of change request on the gui of my project especially the images and icons.

I would like to check them in only if it comes to a point that the requests are very minimal.  with this, I don't like my git repository to be cluttered with images since I have images that are in megabytes in size.

Currently, what I am doing is include almost everything except binaries, object files and images to my git repo.
Then every week, I do a full zip backup of everything.

What I would like to ask is, if there is a way to put files in git without versioning?

I know it defeats the purpose of git but the size of the git repo can be controlled with this way.

To illustrate:

- I have `pic1.jpg`. I would like to put it into git.
- if I will replace `pic1.jpg` with another image but with the same filename, it will just overwrite the `pic1.jpg` and don't do version backups.
  This way the git repo will dramatically increase in size.

This may sound dangerous, but from what I have learned from git is that if you committed a file into it, it will stay there forever.

There is another solution I think of: The project will be fully zipped and placed inside a dropbox  and the developer who is new to the project will get it from the dropbox, extract, do a git fetch, then merge.

I hope someone could share their experience/expertise regarding this.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646700/git-ignore-files-being-tracked-without-deleting-them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if there is a way to put files in git without versioning

The only one proposing that is [`git-annex`](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) (not available on Windows)

I mention in "[Git repository setup with binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956726/6309)" another tool "**[bup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494211/6309)**", which actually store the data in a git-compatible repo.

But if you don't intent to go back often and rebuilt old version of your project, putting those resources (large pictures) in a git repo isn't very useful, and git-annex can help dealing with that state.

Beware of git repo through dropbox, it isn't always safe (see "[Git with Dropbox Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/6309)").

Comment: Thank you so much. We are currently using windows and very inclined with tortoisegit. I will take a look on this one. Thank you